# Signed left shift behaviour

Tags: java, int, bit-shift, signed

```
public class Shift {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
            System.out.println(-0x55555555 << i);
        }
    }

}
```

Running the above code gives the following output

```
-1431655765
1431655766
-1431655764
1431655768
-1431655760
1431655776
-1431655744
1431655808
-1431655680
1431655936
-1431655424
1431656448
-1431654400
1431658496
-1431650304
1431666688
-1431633920
1431699456
-1431568384
1431830528
-1431306240
1432354816
-1430257664
1434451968
-1426063360
1442840576
-1409286144
1476395008
-1342177280
1610612736
-1073741824
-2147483648
```

While testing with an other value (64) gives a more expected result

```
public class Shift {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
            System.out.println(-0x40 << i);
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
-64
-128
-256
-512
-1024
-2048
-4096
-8192
-16384
-32768
-65536
-131072
-262144
-524288
-1048576
-2097152
-4194304
-8388608
-16777216
-33554432
-67108864
-134217728
-268435456
-536870912
-1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

In [the specs (§15.19)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) it's said that :

***`The value of n << s is n left-shifted s bit positions; this is equivalent (even if overflow occurs) to multiplication by two to the power s.`***

Can someone explain the why's of the first output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value of n << s is n left-shifted s bit positions; this is equivalent (even if overflow occurs) to multiplication by two to the power s.

And it's true: this is exactly the result you'd get if you multiplied `-0x55555555` by two to the power of `s`, due to overflow.  In particular, `0x55555555` has alternating 0s and 1s, so you're shifting alternating 0s and 1s into the sign bit, so the sign is flipping every time.

Comment: So why does it keep the sign in the second example?
What's exactly considered as an overflow?

Comment: It keeps the sign in the second example because `-0x40` doesn't have alternating 0s and 1s in its binary representation; its binary representation is `0xFFFFFFC0`, so it still has a 1 for its sign bit when you shift it left (until you shift it by far enough that it's 0).

Comment: An overflow is going to be any result that would "normally" be outside the range -2^31 <= x < 2^31.

Comment: Nevermind for the overflow thing. I don't know why I was thinking of -0x40 as 0x80000040... Completely messed up with the 2's complement representation.. Thanks :)