# Does left shifting a byte change the signed bit in Java?

Tags: java, byte-shifting

I have

```
byte i = 30;
i <<= 3;
System.out.println(i);
```

Which I believe would change `00011110` to `11110000` Does doing this actually put a one into the signed bit, or is the one that would be in the signed bit cut off and the signed bit is changed some other way?

Also, this prints out `-16`. Why is this? I thought `11110000` in base 10 was equal to `-112`, I'm confused where the `-16` comes from.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049720/signed-left-shift-behaviour

Comment: `11110000` is 2's complement form .convert to decimal gives -16

Comment: How does the 2's complement work? Google says you invert the bytes the add 1, but wouldn't that produce `00010000` or positive 16?

Comment: @kneedhelp yes but last step is adding minus .try online calculates `2's complement to decimal`.

Comment: To find out the positive version of a twos complement negative number, flip all the bits and add 1 to the result. `11110000` ⇒ `00001111` ⇒ `00010000` = `16`. Therefore, `11110000` = `-16`.

Comment: `111000` is 240. -112 is `10010000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From right to left, the bits of a byte represent 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and -128.

We call it the sign bit, but really it represents -128.

`11110000` is therefore `16 + 32 + 64 - 128 == -16`.

Comment: Does the compiler treat the first bit any differently than the others?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what's happening here. If the sign bit is a 1, it adds -128 to the output?

Comment: That's right. The sign bit is only treated differently to the others for a few things. For adding and multiplying you can treat all 8 bits in the same way, but when you convert a byte to a string like `"-16" ` the sign bit has to be treated differently.